# How can I find a picture in my Internet cache?

Tags: windows-vista, cache

I visited a Craiglist listing a couple weeks ago that had some pictures I'm trying to retrieve. The listing has since then been deleted, so is there any way I can recover the pictures from my Windows Vista computer if they were cached at some point?

Any hints on how I could find these on my local hard drive if they exist?

Comment: What browser were you using? Also, have you tried a Google search for the page and seeing if the is a 'Cached' link in the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Firefox type `about:cache` on the url to browse the cache.

I don't know if Internet Explorer has something similar but you can google for a cache viewer utility.

For example: [ie cache view](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/ie_cache_viewer.html) utility.